# "Error: DI Exception" when trying to run my angular 2 application?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-services, npm-start

I tried upgrading my angular 2 application to RC5 and ran into some errors with one of the third party libraries I am using so I have decided to go back to RC4. I cloned my repo that was working successfully in RC4, ran npm install, etc, and now am running into this error when I run "npm start":

```
(index):32 Error: Error: DI Exception
    at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:4472:27)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:4602:20)
    at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:4638:20)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:6532:23)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:6560:29)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:6523:29)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByReflectiveDependency (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:6513:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._instantiate (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:6411:40)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._instantiateProvider (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:6382:29)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._new (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:6371:25)
Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
```

I am confused why this is not working now when it worked previously. Something in my environment must have changed to cause these issues. Here is what some of my setup looks like...

main.ts:

```
let appProviders = [
  DivisionProposalsService,
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  LoggedInUser,
  TimelineService,
  UserService,
  LeadService,
  GeneralInfoService,
  FileService,
  Parameters
]

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  appProviders,
  appRouterProviders,
  disableDeprecatedForms(),
 provideForms()
])
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

app.component.ts:

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
  <navigation></navigation>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <!--<proposal-page></proposal-page>-->
`,
directives: [NavigationComponent, DivisionProposalsComponent, ProposalPageComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent {
...
```

I don't really know what other code to show because the error is so generic.

Could these npm install warnings have something to do with it?

npm install

> angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 postinstall C:\test2
>   typings install

typings WARN deprecated 7/25/2016: "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160602141332" is deprecated (updated, replaced or removed)
typings WARN deprecated 8/23/2016: "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160621231320" is deprecated (updated, replaced or removed)

├── core-js (global)
├── jasmine (global)
└── node (global)

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:

npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14

npm WARN @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.5 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.

npm WARN @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.4 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.

npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.0.0-rc.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.3 but none was installed.

npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.0.0-rc.3 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.3 but none was installed.

npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.0.0-rc.3 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.3 but none was installed.

npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.0.0-rc.3 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.3 but none was installed.

npm WARN @angular/router@3.0.0-beta.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.

npm WARN angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.11 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.1 but none was installed.

npm WARN angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.11 requires a peer of @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.1 but none was installed.

npm WARN angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.11 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.

npm WARN angular2-modal@1.1.2 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.

npm WARN ng2-bootstrap@1.0.24 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.

npm WARN ng2-bootstrap@1.0.24 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.

npm WARN ng2-bootstrap@1.0.24 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.

Comment: I would review the `package.json` file, you seem to have a healthy mix of versions showing up in the warning, such as `@angular/core@2.0.0-rc.5` followed by `@angular/http@2.0.0-rc.4`.  I would make sure everything is on the appropriate version and that all the required dependencies, such as core-js are what they should be as well.  Once you've done that, I would almost say blow away your `node_modules` and `typings` (if you have typings) folders and re-run the installs

Comment: Did you switch to using NgModule per http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/08/angular-2-rc5-ngmodules-lazy-loading.html?

Comment: @DaveV Thanks you helped me get on the right track. I removed node_modules and typings and got a new ngmodule error after reinstalling. Then I removed the caret ^ in front of some of the angular related packages I was using which were already depending on RC5 ngmodule stuff. After that I removed and installed one more time and got it to work with the older package versions not dependent on RC5.

Comment: @Dave I was trying to get my RC4 to work again from a fresh clone/install because the ng2-bootstrap package has issues with RC5.